# AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'save'

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to save a pandas DataFrame in binary data formats and book says that pandas objects all have save method which writes the data to disc as a pickle. but when I run the code there is an error. Is there save method for pandas objects in pandas new versions? I'm using pandas 0.25.3

```
import pandas as pd

frame = pd.read_csv('PandasTest.csv')
frame.save('PandasTest_Pickle')
```

The error is:

```
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'save'
```

Comment: The method that saves a DataFrame to a pickle file is called `to_pickle`, not `save`. There are a family of such functions for different file formats (`to_csv`, `to_excel`, `to_hdf`, ...)

Comment: As this command is deprecated, consider using `to_pickle` instead. Source: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.16.2/generated/pandas.DataFrame.save.html

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As others in comment section suggested, use 'to_pickle' and 'read_pickle' methods. For e.g,

```
import pandas as pd

frame=pd.read_csv('data.csv')

frame.to_pickle('frame_pickle')
pd.read_pickle('frame_pickle')
```